# Self Coded RSA Implementation

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

Preface: This is a homework assignment, and I am almost done with it -- it's just this tiny piece that is preventing me from finishing. With this information, please do not write any code for me, but possibly note what I might be doing wrong.

Okay, here is the simple idea.
Use RSA to encrypt/decrypt a file with ECB Mode. This means if there was a block size of 4, and the string was 'testdata', 'test' would be encrypted with the key, written to file, and then 'data' would be encrypted with the key and written to the file.

My implementation is using 128 as the block size, but I'm having a strange error.

Here is my code to encrypt a block of 128 and append to a file:

```
ArrayList<byte[]> bytes = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
String file = read_file(input_file);
int index = 0;
while (index<file.length()) {
    byte[] block = file.substring(index, Math.min(index+128,file.length())).getBytes();
    cipher = new BigInteger(block).modPow(public_exponent, public_modulus).toByteArray();
    bytes.add(cipher);
    append_bytes(output_file, cipher);
    index+=128;
}
```

Encryption works perfectly. Here's why I think that encryption is not the issue:

- Decrypting the data that is being written to the file works
- Adding all encrypted data to a list contains the same data as reading the file
- If decrypting from the list that I mentioned above, decryption works flawlessly.

It's the strangest issue, though.

This produces the right output:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bytes.size(); i++) {
    decrypted = new BigInteger(bytes.get(i)).modPow(d, modulus).toByteArray();
    System.out.print(new String(decrypted));
}
```

But that is useless, because what's the point of being able to decrypt only after encrypting.

This does not work every time, but it does work occassionaly:

```
index = 0;
file = new String(read_bytes(output_file));
while(index < file.length()) {
    byte[] block = file.substring(index, Math.min(index+128,file.length())).getBytes();
    decrypted = new BigInteger(block).modPow(d, modulus).toByteArray();
    System.out.println(new String(decrypted));
    index+= 128;
}
```

I am reading the file the same way that it was wrote to; in blocks of 128. But it does not read it properly, and because of that, decryption fails!

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do directly with Python or C#, so yes, the tags should be removed. I have taken the liberty of doing so.

Comment: There is so much wrong with this. RSA "blocks" are not byte or bit aligned, BigIntegers can be positive or negative, no string codec is specified, and none of the I/O where the alleged problem occurs is shown. Oh, and the alleged error is described with no more clarity than "does not read it properly". How can you expect to get any help with a question like this?

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the cipher-text (which is binary data) into a `String`, then possible running into some charset convertion that messes up everything.

The decryption should read raw bytes. If you need each blocks in a different array, you may use [`Arrays.copyOfRange(original,from,to)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29).

Another approach would be base64-encoding the ciphertext before writing it to the file, then base-64 decoding before decryption.